# IDirect3D9::GetAdapterCount wont find my second video card

Tags: directx, nvidia, directx-9, video-card

My laptop has two video cards, a high powered NVIDIA one and an onboard Intel one.  When I call IDirect3D9::GetAdapterCount however, it only finds the onboard Intel one, probably because the high powered one is being hidden.

I'm able to go into my laptop settings and tell it 'force choose' the NVIDIA card, and then it works, but this is not an acceptable solution for my end-users.   I've also noticed that when I run Battlefield3, it's able to properly find the NVIDIA card even without 'force choose' enabled.  Maybe there's a special white-list that has Battlefield listed?  Or some other secret method?

Any ideas how to acquire that elusive card?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the intel chip is enumeratable?  Quite often its not.  By sticking in a discrete GPU the sandybridge (and older) chipset is generally disabled.  You probably want to check the [Nvidia optimus test tool](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/26992-optimus-test-tools-finally-in-users-hands/).

Answer (score 0):

GetAdapterCount will actually returns count of the monitors in system, not videocards. And as far as I know there is no way to force choose it programmatically.

If you talking about nVidia optimus technology, it choose videochip using driver settings.